# Populating tables using Sprout Forms

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I have a Sprout form with table field. I'm trying to fill it as native Entry form table field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[tableField]" value="">        
<textarea name="fields[tableField][0][col1]" rows="1"></textarea>
<textarea name="fields[tableField][0][col2]" rows="1"></textarea>
<textarea name="fields[tableField][0][col3]" rows="1"></textarea>
```

The data in the table is saved correctly, but after submitting the form, I get an error: **Array to string conversion...**

Tell me please what is the problem.
Thanks in advance.

[image: error]

Comment: I suggest you to ask the creator of the plugin. Those plugin related questions are barely answered in a short period of time. You could inspect the html in your cp form and copy/paste it to your custom form. That's usually the best way. Otherwise you have to wait for someone who uses sprout and this field and is familiar with it

Comment: If the data is saved correctly, could the error you are seeing be happening on your Thank You page or in the Notification Email? The error is saying that somewhere a template is trying to output an array with incorrect syntax. We don't support the Table field natively in Sprout Forms, so it is possible something else needs to get updated to fully support it. Can you try simplifying your Thank you page to just text or disabling any notification emails you have to see if the submission works? If that's the issue, I can respond with additional info.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
I could not find the cause of the error. I replaced the table field with the matrix. It works fine